# extract data.frame name and dependent variable name from nls model in R

Tags: r

Say I have I fit an `nls` model to some data, `d`, in R.

```
#fake data
x<- seq(1,10,by=0.1)
y<- 1*(x / (2 + x))
y<- y + rnorm(0, 0.05, n =length(y))
d<- data.frame(x,y)

#fit the nls model
model <- nls(y ~ v1*(x/(v2 + x)), start=c(v1=0.9,v2=2.1))
```

I want to return from the `model` object the name of the data frame (`d`), and the name of the dependent varaible (`y`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get these values from the model object as follows:

```
# Data frame name
as.character(model$data)

# Dependent variable name
as.character(formula(model)[2])
```

How did I know that, you ask? Well, I didn't, but you can often figure out things like this by looking at the structure of the model object (type `str(model)` in the console) returned by an R function.

For example, in this case, `model` is a list with six elements. The first element, called `m` is itself a list. Here are the first few lines of output:

```
str(model)
```

> ```
> List of 6
>  $ m          :List of 16
>   ..$ resid     :function ()  
>   ..$ fitted    :function ()  
>   ..$ formula   :function ()
> ```

Note that one of the elements of `m` is called `formula` and it's a function. So, I tried typing `formula(model)` in the console and got this:

> ```
> y ~ v1 * (x/(v2 + x))
> ```

Then I typed `str(formula(model))` to see what kind of object `formula()` was actually returning:

> ```
> Class 'formula' length 3 y ~ v1 * (x/(v2 + x))
>   ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
> ```

Notice that it returns an object with three elements (`length 3`). The second element happens to contain the dependent variable name. Wrapping it in `as.character` changes it into a string, which is what I assume you want.

Now for the data frame. Note that one of the list elements returned by `str(model)` is called `data`. So I typed `model$data` in the console and got this:

> ```
> d
> ```

Once again, I wrapped it in `as.character` to turn the output into a string.

There may be better ways to approach this, but don't underestimate what you can accomplish just by poking around inside the object returned by a function.